# Python detect Gaussian Blur

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following codes to detect whether an input image is blurred.

```
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import cv2
import os

def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
    help="path to input directory of images")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=100.0,
    help="focus measures that fall below this value will be considered 'blurry'")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["images"]):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and compute the
    # focus measure of the image using the Variance of Laplacian
    # method
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray)
    text = "Not Blurry"

    # if the focus measure is less than the supplied threshold,
    # then the image should be considered "blurry"
    if fm < args["threshold"]:
        text = "Blurry"
```

To use the script, I run the following command:

```
python detect_blur.py --images images
```

where `images` is the folder name containing a series of photos.

However, the results are quite inaccurate (given that it is categorized that the Laplacian value < 100 is considered as blurry):

It detects this photo is blurred (correct, Laplacian value = 1.26):

[image: Blur Photo]

But it detects this photo is blurred as well (incorrect, Laplacian value = 62.9):

[image: Not blurry photo]

How to make the code more accurate? I would like to specifically detect Gaussian blur, how can I change the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I worked out a library by myself to check for blurry images by checking Laplacian values.

To install the library, use `pip install imgtoolkit`. Then, with this simple script, we can find the blurry images and move them to a separate folder.

```
from imgtoolkit import tools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Find blur photos
    tools.find_blur()
```

Github source code can be found [here](https://github.com/shivanraptor/imgtoolkit).

Answer (score 2):

With the second image, well, objectively it *is* blurry aside from the very bottom.

You might thus get better results if you subdivide each input image to, say, 25 pieces (that is, a 5 x 5 grid) and compute the focus value for each. You could then use e.g. the maximum of the foci (or another measure such as mean or median, if that works better for you?) as the focus value for the full image.

Comment: nice idea of dividing the images to smaller pieces. There are some human portraits that are wrongly identified as well.  Would you mind to provide some sample codes? and how about specifically detect Gaussian Blur? is the Laplacian good enough?